# Create conditional column in Power Query based on list value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to create a conditional column in Excel Power Query that look up a list of companies and return a value like "Yes" if the company column in that given row corresponds with one of the companies in the list.

It should look something like this:

```
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| Company  |        List         | Match |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
| Apple    | Facebook, Instagram | No    |
| Facebook | Facebook, Instagram | Yes   |
+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

Constraint: I cannot create additional rows since the excel sheet will be used for importing information to a system, and therefore needs to be structured in a given way.

I have tried using the built in conditional column functionality in Power Query, but it can only look at a specific column, and not several. And it sees the companies list column as a big string like "Facebook, Instagram" and not separate values. Also, the company list is very long, so it would be very inefficient to create if-statements for each company.

[image: What I have tried]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial table looks something like:

[image: Initial table]

then this code:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({{"Apple", "Facebook"}, {"Facebook, Instagram", "Facebook, Instagram"}}, type table [Company = text, List = text]),
    matchColumn = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "Match", each List.Contains(Text.Split([List], ", "), [Company]), type logical)
in
    matchColumn
```

should give expected output:

[image: Output table]

- I split the list of companies on the delimiter `,` (there is a space after the comma), since that is what you've shown in your question. You can change the code to use `,` if there is no space.
- I've used `true`/`false` (instead of `"YES"`/`"NO"`).
- If any of the company names contain commas (i.e. commas that should be interpreted literally and not as delimiters), then you may get unexpected behaviour/output. `Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter` can help to return a better splitting function, but it requires your values to already be quoted (which they don't appear to be).

---

Alternatively, try:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({{"Apple", "Facebook"}, {"Facebook, Instagram", "Facebook, Instagram"}}, type table [Company = text, List = text]),
    matchColumn = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "Match", each if List.Contains(Text.Split([List], ", "), [Company]) then "AB119" else "AD119", type text)
in
    matchColumn
```

Comment: Thanks! For it to solve my problem I would need it to return a string of text that I can define, and not a logical true/false. I only used "Yes"/"No" as an example, but in retrospect I understand that was a bad choice of example. For example I would like it to return "AB119" if it matches and "AD119" if it does not.

Comment: @torkestativ Have edited answer if you want to have another look. I wasn't able to test the code in the edit though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just to check I understand correctly - do you have a list of Apps and a known list of companies?

If so, you could try:

```
if
List.AnyTrue(List.Transform({
"Instagram",
"Facebook",
"WhatsApp"
}
,(substring) => Text.Contains([List],substring,Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))

then "Facebook"

else if

//then repeat for list of other company products 

else "No Company"
```

Though please note, this method is limited by order - i.e. if the [List] column contained both Apple and Facebook Apps/Products it would only designate it the first company listed in your query.